# Using variable groups of Azure DevOps in application.properties file or is it better to use secured files?

Tags: spring, azure-devops

In my Azure DevOps userinterface I went to Pipelines -> Library -> Variable group. I declared a new group there in order to store private credentials. For my project I want to store the client_id and client_secret in there, so I don't commit them in my application.properties file of my Spring Boot application.

[image: Azure Devops variable group image]

The application.properties items that should contain the variable keys.

```
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.cdb.client-id=
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.cdb.client-secret=
```

I've been looking all over the internet, but I don't manage to find a guide that explains me how to load those variables into my application.properties file.

Is there anyone that can help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [replace token extionsion](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=qetza.replacetokens). All waht you need is to add token to your `application.properties`

```
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.cdb.client-id=#{client_id}#
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.cdb.client-secret=#{client_secret}#
```

and then (if you use YAML it may look like this):

```yaml
- task: qetza.replacetokens.replacetokens-task.replacetokens@3
  displayName: 'Replace tokens'
  inputs:
    targetFiles: |
      **/application.properties
```

Keep in mind to reference you variable group in your pipeline.

Comment: Thanks for your reaction. I requested this extension. As soon as the DevOps administrator approves my request I will post an update here.

Answer (score 0):

Using the replacetokens extension was the working solution for this scenario.

```
- task: replacetokens@3
  ...
```

Was also working and is a bit shorter then:

```
- task: qetza.replacetokens.replacetokens-task.replacetokens@3
  ...
```

Thanks for your answer.